# Concatenating rows and dropping the successive repetitions or repeating elements

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, string-matching

I have a dataframe as follows and I would like to concatenate the rows in the sequence (drop them if there is successive repetition) based on ticket number and identify how they are handed across people.

```
    ticket<- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2")
    name<- c("Olg", "Jan", "Jan", "Olg", "Jan", "Jan","Olg")
    df<- data.frame(ticket, name)
```

I want to create a column called variable called sequence which provides the paths and suppresses the successive repetitions as shown (Olg-Jan-Jan to Olg-Jan and  Olg-Jan-Jan-Olg to Olg-Jan-Olg). Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
   seq<- c("Olg-Jan", "Olg-Jan", ""Olg-Jan", "Olg-Jan-Olg","Olg-Jan-Olg","Olg-Jan-Olg" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a factor (and we could convert it to factor if it wasn't) so we use the underlying numeric factor codes to check for consecutive duplicates and remove them. We use `dplyr` so that we can easily group by `ticket` and chain functions together using the chaining operator (`%>%`).

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% group_by(ticket) %>%
   filter(c(1, diff(as.numeric(name))) !=0) %>%
   summarise(sequence = paste(name, collapse="-"))
```

> ```
>   ticket    sequence
> 1      1     Olg-Jan
> 2      2 Olg-Jan-Olg
> ```

If you want to keep all the rows of the original data frame and just add the sequence, then you can `left_join` the output above to your original data frame:

```
df = df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(ticket) %>%
              filter(c(1, diff(as.numeric(name))) !=0) %>%
              summarise(sequence = paste(name, collapse="-")))
```

> ```
>   ticket name    sequence
> 1      1  Olg     Olg-Jan
> 2      1  Jan     Olg-Jan
> 3      1  Jan     Olg-Jan
> 4      2  Olg Olg-Jan-Olg
> 5      2  Jan Olg-Jan-Olg
> 6      2  Jan Olg-Jan-Olg
> 7      2  Olg Olg-Jan-Olg
> ```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you correctly....

```
> df_to_list <- split(df, df$ticket)
> df_to_list
$`1`
  ticket name
1      1  Olg
2      1  Jan
3      1  Jan

$`2`
  ticket name
4      2  Olg
5      2  Jan
6      2  Jan
7      2  Olg
```

Now we're going to loop over and unlist the names, then remove cases where the same name appears in succession, and bind.

```
new_df <- lapply(df_to_list, function(i){

  a <- as.character(unlist(i[['name']]))

  endr <- length(a) - 1
  b <- sapply(1:endr, function(x){
    a[x] != a[x+1]
  })

  c <- a[b]

  paste0(c, collapse = "-")

}) %>% melt %>% select(ticket = L1, seq = value)

> new_df
  ticket         seq
1      1     Olg-Jan
2      2 Olg-Jan-Olg
```

Is this what you're after?

Note: Speed difference in using group_by method vs this way produced interesting output timing.  I replicated the set to 14000 rows and named the new data frame `addf` and wrapped both solutions into separate functions `using_group` and `no_group.

```
> system.time(using_group(addf))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.000   0.011 
> system.time(no_group(addf))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004
```